# Is there a file limit file_put_contents using base64

Tags: php

I am using the following php script:

```
<?php

$filename =  $_POST['newFileName'];

file_put_contents('images/'.$filename, base64_decode($_POST['url']));

echo 'images/'.$filename;

?>
```

It is working fine upto approx 2-3 meg image files.

However the larger files are not uploaded and I just get 'images/' returned.

Phpinfo shows :

upload_max_filesize 40M
post_max_size 8M
memory_limit 120M

The files that are failing are 4 meg / 5 meg.

Any Ideas ?

Comment: Why are you uploading files as base64-encoded strings instead of as *files*?

Comment: The image data is encoded in a mobile app as base64.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the input guys.

It seems that the issue was the fact that although PHP has an upload limit of 8 meg I have since found out that when they are converted to base64 the file size increases by approx 33%.

So although I was selecting files under 8 meg the actaul sent size was larger.

Unfortunately the clients host (1and1.co.uk) states that this limit cannot be increased on any of their packages.

So 4 meg image size will be the limit. Fingers crossed the client is happy.

Cheers

Mr Warby.